# Does res.writehead actually write to the head of my html page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js

In my node.js webpage I'm making a page preview similar to the Facebook link preview.  I'm making a call to get the html of the page, and use it to create the preview.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    data: { "html": url },
    url: "/htmlTest",
    success: function (data) {
            imgArray = [];
            $('img', data).each(function () {
                imgArray.push(this.src);
            });
  ...
```

This is the server-side code that handles the request.

```
app.get('/htmlTest', function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, { 'content-type': 'text/html' });
        request(req.query.html, function (error, response, body) {
            if (error) {
                res.write(error.toString());
                res.end('\n');
            }
            else if (response.statusCode == 200) {
                res.write(body);
                res.end('\n');
            }
        })
});
```

Now what I've been noticing, is that it will just insert any css the other page uses into my page, which can really screw everything up.  Why is this happening?

Also, while I'm at it, does anyone have any better ideas for a facebook-style page preview?

Comment: `res.writeHead(200, { 'content-type': 'text/html' });` appears to just be writing a header (not html content), though i haven't dove into node just yet. Your problem is more likely to be getting caused by `res.write(body);`

Comment: Do you know what headers are? I suggest you learn and understand how the HTTP protocol itself works because attempting to make anything productive with Node. HTTP responses contain two distinctive parts - headers (content type/status/etc) and body (the actual payload).

Comment: Yeah, and honestly that's what their documentation makes it sound like, but the css is getting into my page somehow.

Comment: `writeHead` simply writes HTTP header information (status, content settings), while `write` actually writes the content you want on your webpage. It looks like you're downloading an HTML page, and returning the entire HTML page, which includes the `<head>` tag (which is where the css is probably located).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  `writeHead` writes HTTP headers to the underlying TCP stream.  It has absolutely nothing to do with HTML.

You're running into an issue because your server returns the wholesale HTML content of the requested URL.  You then pass this string into jQuery, which is apparently adding contained CSS styles into *your* document.

Generally, it is a terrible idea to take random code from a user-supplied URL and run in the context of your page.  It opens you to gaping security holes – the CSS artifacts you're seeing are one example.

To be blunt, your code has numerous problems, so bear with me as I point out some issues.

```
app.get('/htmlTest', function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, { 'content-type': 'text/html' });
```

Here, you respond to the browser with a success status (`200`) *beore* your server actually does anything.  This is incorrect: you should only respond with either a success or error code after you know if the request succeeded or failed.

```
        request(req.query.html, function (error, response, body) {
            if (error) {
                res.write(error.toString());
                res.end('\n');
            }
```

Here would be a good place to respond with an error code, since we know that the request did actually fail.  `res.send(500, error)` would do the trick.

```
            else if (response.statusCode == 200) {
                res.write(body);
                res.end('\n');
            }
```

And here's where we could respond with a success code.  Rather than use `writeHead`, use Express's `set` and `send` methods – things like `Content-Length` will be correctly set:

```
res.set('Content-Type', 'text/html');
res.send(body);
```

Now what happens if `response.statusCode != 200`?  You don't handle that case.  `error` is only set in the case of network errors (such as inability to connect to the target server).  The target server can still respond with a non-200 status, and your node server would never respond to the browser.  In fact, the connection would hang open until the user kills it.  This could be fixed with a simple `else res.end()`.

---

Even with these issues resolved, we still haven't addressed the fact that it's not a good idea to try to parse arbitrary HTML in the browser.

If I were you, I'd use something that parses HTML into a DOM on the server, and then I'd return only the necessary information back to the browser as JSON.  [cheerio](https://github.com/MatthewMueller/cheerio) is the module you probably want to use – it looks just like jQuery, only it runs on the server.

I'd do this:

```
var cheerio = require('cheerio'), url = require('url'), request = require('request');

app.get('/htmlTest', function(req, res) {
    request(req.query.url, function(err, response, body) {
        if (err) res.send(500, err); // network error, send a 500
        else if (response.status != 200) res.send(500, { httpStatus: response.status }); // server returned a non-200, send a 500
        else {
            // WARNING!  We should probably check that the response content-type is html
            var $ = cheerio.load(body); // load the returned HTML into cheerio
            var images = [];
            $('img').each(function() {
                // Image srcs can be relative.
                // You probably need the absolute URL of the image, so we should resolve the src.
                images.push(url.resolve(req.query.url, this.src));
            });

            res.send({ title: $('title').text(), images: images }); // send back JSON with the image URLs
        }
    });
});
```

Then from the browser:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/htmlTest',
    data: { url: url },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        // data.images has your image URLs
    },
    error: function() {
        // something went wrong
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm kind of self-taught, so this answer was a HUGE help.  One small edit: (response.status != 200) should be (response.statusCode != 200)